# Count how many times two values occur in the same row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to pull a few reports for a client and I'm having trouble nailing one of queries down. I'd like to count the amount of times each customer has visited each location.

Sales Table

```
CustNo|StoreNo
  2      10
  2      10
  3      5
  3      10
  2      20
```

Return Query

```
CustNo|StoreNo|Count
  2     10      2
  2     20      1
  3     5       1
  3     10      1
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Basic aggregation `SELECT custno, storeno, COUNT(*) FROM tab GROUP BY custno, storeno ORDER BY custno, storeno`

Comment: What have you tried to do? Show us the query even if it not correct.

Comment: I was trying to use HAVING in the group by. And I was originally joining two other tables. Last work day before a long weekend, my mind is wondering :D thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `group by` keyword like:

```
select CustNo,StoreNo,Count(*) as VisitCount
from Sales
group by CustNo, StoreNo
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I was over thinking this one to death.

Comment: You are welcome. I appreciate if you select the answer as the correct answer by clicking the tick on the left of this answer. @AndrewGrabski